# Code the shortest for incremental adding up until > 100 in Hack Assembly Language

Tags: assembly

You can find the Hack Assembly Language specification here: http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/course/2002/nand2tet/docs/ch_4_machine_language.pdf

You can download the Hack Computer emulator here: 
http://www.nand2tetris.org/software.php

The goal is to write something similar to this:

```
int i = 1;
while(i<100){
    i = i+i;
}
```

My solution is here:

```
@17     // Set Register A to 17
M = 1   // Set M[17] = 1
@17     // Set Register A to 17  --> This is location 2 btw
D = M   // Set Register D to value stored in M[17]
A = D   // Copy the value found in Register D to A
D = D+A // Set value in D = D + A
@17     // Set Register A to 17
M = D   // Store the value in M[17] to the value of Register D
@100    // Store value 100 in Register A
D = D-A // Set value in D to D - 100
@2      // Set Register A to 2
D;JLT   // If D<0 D is still not greater than 100. Goto location 2
```

Can you come up with something shorter?

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand your question. This site is mainly for programming competitions. Do you want to make a codegolf competition? Or do you only want some tips?

Comment: @jakube competition

Comment: Then you should edit the question a little bit. 'Something similar to this' is very vague. I would formulate this in another way: E.g. Find the smallest power of two, that is `>= 100`. In this way the goal is more clearer. Also, I would generalize it to `>= n`, where `n` is an input from the user (Not sure how to do this in assembly though). Otherwise someone will hardcode the solution 128.